# grep from a list of strings and regex

Tags: regex, grep

I'm looking to search a file for domains and IP addresses and also some other particular words, such as POST, GET, and a few others. I'm currently using the following command:

```
grep --color -i -f search-terms strings.txt
```

An example of search-terms:

```
<!-- url -->
[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]\-]*\.[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]\-]*\.[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]\-]*$
<!-- ip address -->
[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}
<!-- useful words -->
http
post
get
```

It seems to work reasonably well, but if I put the word **http** at the start of the search-term file, I get a segfault. Here is my example strings.txt.

```
hello world this is a search
for anything like a domain such as http://www.me.com
and something else like the word GET
http://google.com
Here is an IP address 10.0.0.1
Here is the word POST.
```

Error:

```
$ grep --color -i -f search-terms strings.txt
for anything like a domain such as http://www.me.com
and something else like the word GET
http://google.com
Here is an IP address 10.0.0.1
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: It is working fine for me on gnu and BSD grep

Comment: Working for me on: `grep (GNU grep) 2.25`, `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`, and `grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`.  There's one I can reproduce the error on, which is on an older FreeBSD system - but i can't get the version of grep from it.  There **is** no version option nor is it in the man page.   What OS are you on ??  Tried updating grep ??  Does it work without --color ?

Comment: this happens on OSX, bizarrely I don't get the error when not using --color. Interesting.